# How To Customise Share Information For Each Individual Video on a Facebook iFrame Tab?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-javascript-sdk

I have a facebook iframe tab which has a few youtube videos on it which are pulled directly from a json response provided by the youtube api.

When you select a thumbnail the video is embedded at the top of the tab and can then be played.

Also displayed underneath the embedded video is the title, description, views and a share button.

At the moment the share information is the same for every video and I am racking my brains how to customise it for each video, even if it means making an ajax call.

Here's the related code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$('.share_button').live('click', function(e){
    // fade out video to stop it conflicting with dialogue box
$('#player').fadeOut('slow');
    e.preventDefault();
    FB.ui(
    {
        method: 'feed',
        name: 'generic name',
        link: 'generic link',
        picture: 'generic image',
        caption: 'generic caption',
        description: 'generic description'
    },
    function(response) {
        // fade video back in once the dialogue box is closed
        $('#player').show('slow');     
    });
});
```

The complete code for my tab is:

```
$url = 'http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?max-results=20&alt=jsonc&orderby=published&format=5&safeSearch=none&author=CHANNELID&v=2';
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $url);
$body = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
$data = json_decode($body, true);

?>
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
        appId : 'XXXXXXXXX',
        status : true, // check login status
        cookie : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
        xfbml : true // parse XFBML
    });
};

(function() {
var e = document.createElement('script');
e.src = document.location.protocol + '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
e.async = true;
document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
}());
</script>


<div id="placeholder" style="font-family:Helvetica; max-width:500px; margin:0 0 20px 0;">
<div id="player"><iframe width="480" height="274" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/<?php echo $data['data']['items'][1]['id']; ?>" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen wmode="Opaque"></iframe></div>
<div id="title" style=" font-size:14px; font-weight:bold; color:#3B5998; margin:2px 0 3px 0;"><?php echo $data['data']['items'][1]['title']; ?> </div>
<div id="views" style="color:#BBB; font-size:12px;"><?php echo $data['data']['items'][1]['viewCount'];?> views</div>
<div id="description" style="font-size:14px;"><?php echo $data['data']['items'][1]['description'];?></div>
<img src = "../images/share_button.png" class="share_button" id="1" style="cursor:pointer;">
<div id="hr" style="padding:5px 0 10px 0; float:left; border-bottom: 1px solid #96CC90; width:480px; margin:0 0 15px 0;"></div>
</div>

<?php
$i = 0;

foreach($data['data']['items'] as $item) {
$id = $item['id'];
$thumb = $item['thumbnail']['sqDefault'];
?>
<div class="video" id="<?php echo $i; ?>" style="font-family:Helvetica; float:left; max-width:150px; min-height:130px; margin:0 0px 20px 10px; cursor:pointer;">
    <div class="thumb" style="position:relative; left:0; top:0;">
        <img src="<?php echo $item['thumbnail']['sqDefault'];?>" title="<?php echo $description;?>" style="position:relative; top:0; left:0px;"/>
        <img src="../images/play-thumb.png" style="position:absolute; top:30px; left:45px;"/>
    </div>
    <div class="title" style="font-size:14px; font-weight:bold; color:#3B5998; margin:2px 0 3px 0;"><?php echo $item['title']; ?></div>
    <div class="views" style="font-size:12px; cursor:text;"><?php echo $item['viewCount'];?> views</div>
</div>

<?php
$i++;
}
?>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

$('.share_button').live('click', function(e){
    $('#player').fadeOut('slow');
    e.preventDefault();
    FB.ui(
    {
        method: 'feed',
        name: 'Generic Name',
        link: 'Generic Link',
        picture: 'Generic Picture',
        caption: 'Generic Caption',
        description: 'Generic Description'
    },
    function(response) {
            $('#player').show('slow');     
        });
});

$('.video').click(function() {
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    showVideo(id);
});

function showVideo(id)
{
    $('#placeholder').fadeOut('slow');

    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: '//www.domain.com/facebook/2011/video-player/youtube.php',
        data: 'id='+ id,
        beforeSend: function() {
            $('#placeholder').html('<img src="../images/youtube-loader.gif" style="min-height:274px;"/>');
        },
        complete: function(){
            //something
        },
        success: function(data) {
            $('#placeholder').html(data);
            $('#placeholder').fadeIn('slow');
        }
    });
}
});
</script>
```

**youtube.php**

```
if (isset($_GET['id']))
{
    $arrayId = $_GET['id'];

    $url = 'http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?max-results=20&alt=jsonc&orderby=published&format=5&safeSearch=none&author=CHANNELID&v=2';
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $url);
    $body = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    $data = json_decode($body, true);

    $video = $data['data']['items'][$arrayId]['id'];
    $title = $data['data']['items'][$arrayId]['title'];
    $views = $data['data']['items'][$arrayId]['viewCount'];

    $description = $data['data']['items'][$arrayId]['description'];
    $description = str_replace('uk.opticalexpress.com', '', $description);
    $description = str_replace('-', '', $description);
    $description = trim($description);

    $embed = 'https://www.youtube.com/embed/'.$video;

    $message = "<div id='player'><iframe style='z-index:9999;'width='480' height='274' src='". $embed ."' frameborder='0' allowfullscreen wmode='Opaque'></iframe></div>\n";   
    $message .= "<div id='title' style='font-size:14px; font-weight:bold; color:#3B5998; margin:2px 0 3px 0;'>". $title ."</div>\n";
    $message .= "<div id='views' style='color:#BBB; font-size:12px;'>". $views ." views</div>\n";
    $message .= "<div id='description' style='font-size:14px;'>". $description ."</div>\n";
    $message .= "<img src = '../images/share_button.png' class='share_button' id='". $arrayId."' style='cursor:pointer;'>";
    $message .= "<div id='hr' style='padding:5px 0 10px 0; float:left; border-bottom: 1px solid #96CC90; width:480px; margin:0 0 15px 0;'></div>\n";

    echo $message;

}

?>
```

If anything is unclear just let me know and I will try and explain it better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're sharing the link to the Tab on the Fan Page there is no way to customize the text that appears as the description on Facebook. They use the page's description by default and PAGE_NAME | TAB_TITLE as the title.

**But there's a workaround:**
You simply share a URL on your server where you can control the Open Graph tags and display them depending on the video that has been shared. If a user now clicks such a shared link, you can simply redirect them to the Tab on your Facebook Page.

If you also need some way of deep linking to the shared video, you can use the URL parameter "app_data" which get's passed to your App's iFrame.

Comment: thanks for the tip. I think this might be possible if I am able to specify the variables for each share button. A rubbish way to do it would be a different `click` method for every video

Comment: I would just store the URL to share in the button's rel tag, then you could have one global click function...

Comment: yes but I need individual name, caption and description parameters for each of the videos, so if I click the first video, it posts to my wall with the title and description of the actual youtube video that is pulled from the api.

Comment: I don't see your problem. When you use the workaround described by me you can have a different title, caption, description for your videos...

Comment: hmm, I am getting slightly confused. So if I only specify the `link` parameter and that link has some Facebook `og` meta tags on it then that will fill out the `caption, description, title` etc. for me?

Comment: No. You would share a link like http://www.yourdomain.com/share.php?video_id=XYZ then you use the URL parameter XYZ to fetch the info from YouTube and output the correct Open Graph Tags. This just happens in case the user agent visiting the site identifies itself as Facebook, if a regular user visits the such a URL you redirect him to http://www.facebook.com/YourFanPage?sk=app_11224365463&app_data=VIDEO_ID. Pretty simple ;-)

Comment: I see. I am just trying to think how to do this, I have just added the dynamic Open Graph Tags to my `youtube.php` which is called from my index page and tried setting the link in the `FB.ui` function to `youtube.php?id=1` but that's actually what's appearing in the dialogue box still.

Comment: Can you give us a link where I can inspect the page? Maybe this will make it easier :-)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6001/discussion-between-martincarlin87-and-bjorn-kaiser)